# want to use whatsapp account in 2phones

Tags: applications

I have 2 phones with same MAC address and same iP address  Samsung grand and Samsung core with me I used my sim card in grand there is no sim in core I just use it for Internet through wifi is it possible to use same whtsapp account in both phones without using QR code once I tried doing it but when I open whatsapp in 2nd phone it request verification in my 1 phone

Comment: Two phones with same IP? How's that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't register the same WhatsApp account on multiple phones at once.

From WhatsApp's [FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/21009863)

> Your WhatsApp account can only be verified with one number on one
>   device.

Here's a workaround:

Use WhatsApp web on the second phone, that way you'll be able to see your messages on both phones.

On the primary phone, open WhatsApp, in the menu click on "WhatsApp web"

Now, on the second phone, open your browser, and go to [web.whatsapp.com](http://web.WhatsApp.com) then, go to your browsers menu, and click on "desktop site" (depending on your browser, the name of that setting might differ)

Now scan the QR code using the first phone. You will now be able to use both phones with the same WhatsApp account.

This is not ideal, but that's the only way to have the same account on two phones at the same time.